# Side Bar Menu in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, side-menu

I'm MVC .Net Developer and just a beginner in Xamarin.ios. I want to implement side bar menu slider in my app but I'm not understanding how to design it in storyboard. I've gone through some links as follows.

https://components.xamarin.com/view/sidebarnavigation
https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.SideMenu

Please provide me some helpful links and suggestions for it.
Any help is appreciated. Thank You

Comment: From your first link(SidebarNavigation), it has the storyboard sample. But you also need to create the Navigation by code, then put your storyboard ViewController in it. If you do need some help, I can make a sample for you.

Comment: Thanks Land, I accomplish it by using xamarin.sidemenu library.

Comment: OK, glad you did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the split view controller. When you create the new xamarin ios project you should select that as the template. You will need to understand UITableviews to create the navigation pane, but there are plenty of resources on that.

If you want a more customizable option I would recommend looking at syncfusion which is free to use for small organizations and developers. Here is a link to there site on how to create a custom navigation pane: https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin-ios/navigationdrawer

Hope this helps. If you would like more specific info, comment and let me know. Xamarin can be kind of difficult to get into but it's a great way to build apps once you get used to it.